# How to sync .so file with project in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, .so

I add .so file to app\src\main\jniLibs\libs directory as below:

```
app
...main
.......jniLibs
..............libs
..................armeabi
.........................libjsqlite.so
..................armeabi-v7a
.........................libjsqlite.so
..................x86
.........................libjsqlite.so
```

and after sync the project. But android studio doesn't know package from libjsqlite and couldn't import libraries to code. I tried different way at stackoverflow but I couldn't. Is there any useful way?
It's my project info:

```
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.masterngo"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Thanks